# I can't find the bug in this c program

Tags: c, arrays

I found this in a tutorial. It is a program to print the given array backward. But it doesn't print the array backward, cause it has a bug. It says I should find the bug, which I can't.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int ara[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};

  int i, j, temp;

  for(i = 0, j = 9; i < 10; i++, j--)
  {
    temp = ara[j];
    ara[j] = ara[i];
    ara[i] = temp;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  {
    printf("%d\n", ara[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: you want `i < 10 / 2` instead of `i < 10` in first for-loop.

Comment: print the array at each step and you will see the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap twice be same as do nothing. Make it swap once only.

```
for(i = 0, j = 9; i < 5; i++, j--)
{
    temp = ara[j];
    ara[j] = ara[i];
    ara[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fish. I'll be back tomorrow for more. Make sure to have it ready. Salmon this time.

Comment: Got it and I'm sorry. But I dont think its a good idea using a debugger to solve such problem. Basicly I do this in a exam, without a computer, not to say a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

The bug is that the algorithm work by swapping the place of items in the array, but it iterates over too many elements. When `i` has iterated over the 5 first elements, the array is backwards. But the iteration continues over the last 5 which puts all elements back in the original position.

You can easily find this out by yourself by printing the whole array at each lap in the loop...

Answer (score 1):

The above code is swapping ara[i] and ara[j] as i moves from 0->9 and j moves from 9->0.
The eventual result is all the numbers return to there original position.
Make your 1st for loop look like below if you want to reverse the original array.

```
for(i = 0, j = 9; i < j; i++, j--)
```

OR

If you just want to print it backward, the latter for loop is sufficient just modify it to

```
for(i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
```